# Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.BuildDetail error

Tags: deployment, build, tfs

I have a TFS 2013 RC install running VS 19,12, and 13 on the build agents. I have a build definition using the CopyDirectory action from the toolbox and when I place anything other than a hard-coded path in either the source or destination box, I get this error
 The build process failed validation. Details: Validation Error: The private implementation of activity '1: DynamicActivity' has the following validation error:   Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "BuildDetail.DropLocation".'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.BuildDetail' is not accessible in this context because it is 'Friend'.
I have googled this and nothing seems to come up that works.
Any ideas would be great, as we are blocked on using this.
Thanks,
Devin

Comment: You should upgrade your TFS server to the RTM of 2013 as soon as you can.

Comment: I got it to work using the instructions in [http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/49f11ed9-9fa8-4c20-952a-d39ee7e71051/can-no-longer-user-builddetaildroplocation-for-copydirectory-with-tfs-2013-using-build-process?forum=tfsbuild](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/49f11ed9-9fa8-4c20-952a-d39ee7e71051/can-no-longer-user-builddetaildroplocation-for-copydirectory-with-tfs-2013-using-build-process?forum=tfsbuild)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you need to use the 2013 build template if you are using the 2013 Build Agent. If you don't want to, or can't, upgrade your template you should reinstall the 2012 build agent which works fine with 2013.

The new templates are on the server, rather than in VC, but you can download them from the build definition screen and check them in if you need to customize them...

So two solutions:

1. Upgrade your templates to 2013
2. Downgrade your build agent to 2012 and use the existing templates